# Display Python HTML Table in Body of Email

Tags: python

I wrote a python script that queries my DB and displays data in HTML table format. How can i get this code to display into an email in the form of a table?

I tried pasting the code inside html tags on the second script(EMAIL) but it does not read python code only HTML.

```
            import pyodbc
            import cgi

            def htmlTop():
                print("""Content-type:text/html\n\n
                      <!DOCTYPE html>
                      <html lang='en'>
                      <head>
                        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
                        <title>My Tabmle</title>
                        </head>
                        <body>""")
            def selectCOAStatus(cnxn, cursor):
                cursor.execute('''SELECT * from mytable''')
                data = cursor.fetchall()
                return data

            def htmlTail():
                print("""</body>
                    </html>""")

            def connectDB():
                conn_str = (
                    r'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
                    r'SERVER=test;'
                    r'DATABASE=test;'
                    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
                )
                cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
                cursor = cnxn.cursor()
                return cnxn, cursor



            def displayData(data):
                print("<table border='1'")
                print("<tr>")
                print("<th>Date</th>")
                print("<th>Count</th>")
                print("<th>Status</th>")
                print("</tr>")

                for row in data:
                    print("<tr>")
                    print("<td>{0}</td>".format(row[0]))
                    print("<td>{0}</td>".format(row[1]))
                    print("<td>{0}</td>".format(row[2]))
                    print("</tr>")
                print("</table>")

            if __name__ == "__main__":
                try:
                    htmlTop()
                    cnxn, cursor = connectDB()
                    data = selectCOAStatus(cnxn, cursor)
                    cursor.close()
                    displayData(data)
                    htmlTail()
                except:
                    cgi.print_exception()
```

EMAIL CODE

import smtplib

```
            from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
            from email.mime.text import MIMEText

            # me == my email address
            # you == recipient's email address
            me = "test@aol.com"
            you = "test@aol.com"

            # Create message container - the correct MIME type is 
            multipart/alternative.
            msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
            msg['Subject'] = "Link"
            msg['From'] = me
            msg['To'] = you

            # Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML 
            version).
            text = "Hi!\nHow are you?\nHere is the link you 
            wanted:\nhttp://www.python.org"
            html = htmlTop()

            # Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and 
            text/html.
            part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
            part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

            # Attach parts into message container.
            # According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, 
             in this case
            # the HTML message, is best and preferred.
            msg.attach(part1)
            msg.attach(part2)

            # Send the message via local SMTP server.
            s = smtplib.SMTP('email.fpl.com')
            # sendmail function takes 3 arguments: sender's address, 
             recipient's address
            # and message to send - here it is sent as one string.
            s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
            s.quit()
```

I expect this HTML table to display on body of my email.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to to data into the table. I fixed my for loop to iterate through all rows and return the value. It is only returning one row though while my query returns multiple other rows. Why is this happening?

import pyodbc
                import cgi
                import html

```
            conn_str = (
                    r'DRIVER=test'
                    r'SERVER=test;'
                    r'DATABASE=test;'
                    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
                )
            cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
            cursor = cnxn.cursor()


            cursor.execute('''SELECT * from my table '''
            for row in cursor:
                    html_code = """
                    <!doctype html>
                <html>
                <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>Untitled Document</title>
                <body>
                    <table border='1'
                    <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Count</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{}</td>
                        <td>{}</td>
                        <td>{}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    </body>
                    </html>""".format(row[0],row[1],row[2])
            print(html_code)


            import smtplib

            from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
            from email.mime.text import MIMEText

            # me == my email address
            # you == recipient's email address
            me = "test@aol.com"
            you = "test@aol.com"

            # Create message container - the correct MIME type is 
            multipart/alternative.
            msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
            msg['Subject'] = "Link"
            msg['From'] = me
            msg['To'] = you

            # Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
            text = "Hi!\nHow are you?\nHere is the link you 
            wanted:\nhttp://www.python.org"
            html = html_code

            # Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
            part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
            part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

            # Attach parts into message container.
            # According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this 
            case
            # the HTML message, is best and preferred.
            msg.attach(part1)
            msg.attach(part2)

            # Send the message via local SMTP server.
            s = smtplib.SMTP('email.fpl.com')
            # sendmail function takes 3 arguments: sender's address, recipient's 
            address
            # and message to send - here it is sent as one string.
            s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
            s.quit()
```

Comment: I know this is too late. Just for future users as reference for a result, "html_code =" should be replaced by "html_code +="

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
print("<td>%s</td>" % row[0] )
```

Also a simpler approach for html email

```
from mailer import Mailer
from mailer import Message

message = Message(From="me@example.com",
              To="you@example.com")
message.Subject = "An HTML Email"
message.Html = """<p>Hi!<br>
               How are you?<br></p>"""

sender = Mailer('smtp.example.com')
sender.send(message)
```

Comment: Thank you. The mailer code is way more efficient and easier to use. However, my code works but the loop only is bringing me back "ONE" row into the table. I have more than one row if i run the query seperate.