# How to insert python html table into html content

Tags: python, html, dataframe, email

I have a dataframe like as below. I already referred this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57434136/display-python-html-table-in-body-of-email). Don't mark it as duplicate please

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'email_id': ['abc@gmail.com;test1@gmail.com','abc@gmail.com;def@yahoo.com','abc@gmail.com','ace@gmail.com','ace@gmail.com','pqr@gmail.com','pqr@gmail.com'],
             'location': ['ANZ_KOR_ASN','ANZ_KOR','c','IND_GER','e','f','g'],
             'dept_access':[10,11,12,13,14,15,16]})
```

I styled the dataframe using `style` properties like below

```
s = data.style.set_properties(**{'border': '1px black solid !important','font-size': '9pt'}).set_table_attributes(
    'style="border-collapse:collapse"').set_table_styles([{
        'selector': '.col_heading',
        'props': 'background-color: white; font-size:9pt; color: black; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px black solid !important;'
}])
```

And converted into a HTML table like below

```
output = s.hide(axis='index').to_html()
```

I try to insert this html table `output` inside my email html body shown below

```
"""
<html><body>
<p>Dear Team </p>
<p>sjhfkajsfbjkasbkjas</p>
<p>please review and confirm your views on the below </p>
 1. Is account still valid? <br>
 2. Does account still required for the user? <br>
 3. Are roles currently permission to the users’ account still valid as per his/her current role?<br>
 <p> Please find the table below which indicates the reasons </p>
 <table> output </table> # inserting output within table htm tag doesn't work
 output # just inserting output doesn't work
 <p>Appreciate your feedback by <b><u>18th March 2021.</u></b></p>
 Regards,<br>
 ABC<br>
</body></html>"""
```

But this results in incorrect output (showing a partial snapshot where table was expected to be seen but it displays just table variable - `output`)

[image]

I expect my output to be like as below

[image]

Comment: Replace beginning `"""` by `f"""` and `output` by `{output}`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher - This worked like a charm. would you mind writing it as an answer for the benefit of others?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use Jinja:
https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/

Here a quickstart guide:
https://github.com/marchon/Jinja2-Quickstart

Comment: thanks. good to know but for my problem, the above comment by @Michael Butscher was simple to implement and it worked well